# JavaFx remove item from TilePane

Tags: layout, javafx-8

What I am trying to do is have a button with three lines of text on it.
The first line is always present. The second and third line are created as TilePane  objects with three elements in them. What I am trying to do is optionally remove either the end two elements of the second and third row or alternatively the middle  item depending on a configuration parameter.

What I have tried is the following:

```
 firstRow.getChildren().addAll(leftFront, leftCentre, leftBack);
        secondRow = new TilePane();
        secondRow.getChildren().addAll(rightFront, rightCentre, rightBack);
        leftCentre.visibleProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {

                firstRow.getChildren().remove(leftBack);
                firstRow.getChildren().remove(leftFront);
            } else {
                firstRow.getChildren().remove(leftCentre);

            }
        });
        leftCentre.visibleProperty().bind(labelProp);
        rightCentre.visibleProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                secondRow.getChildren().remove(rightBack);
                secondRow.getChildren().remove(rightFront);

            } else {
                secondRow.getChildren().remove(rightCentre);

            }
        });
        rightCentre.visibleProperty().bind(labelProp);
```

Where the elements with left and right named items are the ones I want to remove or keep depending on the `SimpleBooleanProperty labelProp`. If I set `labelProp` to false the four outer elements appear. However if I set the `labelProp` to true only the top line of the three appear.

So what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Worked out my problem. It appears that the initial value of the BooleanProperty was removing the values I expected to see when it was initialised. So when I tried to make them reappear the Nodes had been removed.

Is there a way to make the elements in a TilePane to aligned? For example

```
 First1    First2

Second1   Second2
```

Is what I am seeing on the screen as I set the TilePane aligment to CENTER. What I want to see is:

```
First1   First2

Second1  Second2
```

so it looks a little neater.